# frame rate is very low for android game developed by flash CS5

Tags: android, flash, frame, flash-cs5, rate

I am porting my flash games on android. I have ported 3 successfully. But the problem with all of them is they are giving very low frame rate near about 7-8. And I have observed 1 thing that frame rate always varies. Sometimes it goes upto 45 and again in next frame it comes to 3-4 and again goes to 15-16.

I am quite confused. Please let me know if anyone is having any idea about this.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered the fact that the new Android phones are as fast as 8 years old PCs? Have you tried to start your game on 1 GHz PC?

Answer (score 0):

Best thing you can do is look at the areas of your game which are going down to 3 - 4 frames per second, and see what's going on in those compared to the others which are performing as you'd expect. Try and reduce the work being done in those areas where it slows down, deferring it to other parts of the system if possible. I'm by no means a flash expert, I don't know if this is possible. However, this is basic optimization techniques in other environments, including Android's native Java.